# Question regarding unexplained substitution by professor MIT OCW

Tags: calculus, integration

Watching a video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv9kVDcj7yo).

At [this](https://youtu.be/Bv9kVDcj7yo?t=2521) point, the professor has $$a^2\left(\cfrac{\theta}{2}+\cfrac{\sin\theta \cos\theta}{2}\right)+C$$
$$=\cfrac{a^2\arcsin\left(\cfrac{y}{a}\right)}{2}+\cfrac{a\sin\theta \,a\cos\theta}{2}+C$$

We see that $y=a\sin\theta$

My question is how he got $a\cos\theta$, which actually $=x$, if $y=a\sin\theta$?

The professor does not explain.

Answer (score 1):

You have $y=a\sin \theta$, then
$$y^2=a^2\sin^2\theta=a^2(1-\cos^2 \theta)=a^2-a^2\cos^2 \theta$$
Adding $a^2\cos^2 \theta$ and substracting $y^2$ to  both sides, we have
$$a^2\cos^2 \theta=a^2-y^2$$
Hence $a\cos \theta=\sqrt{a^2-y^2}$.